# How to fix the ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss5.x

I have created one war file. I am using jboss server and eclipse IDE. If I run the project it shows the error message. Can anyone help me to find out the this error.

```
`12:55:42,721 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
at Utilities.ReportUtil.startTesting(ReportUtil.java:34)
at Test_Scripts.Hybrid_Framework.startTesting(Hybrid_Framework.java:61)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

Comment: Add `Utilities.ReportUtil` to your question. In this class you have a substring that not work.

Comment: The is the relevat part of the code `startTesting(ReportUtil.java:34)` Please add that.

Answer (score 0):

This exception thrown when index `l` in `string.substring(l)` is greater than string length.

```
        String string ="";
        string.substring( 1 );
```

this code will throw

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1918)
```

So may be you are trying to get a part from incoming empty string.